# How to use python plot a bar chart which have different categories for each bar?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want statistic the uptime of my PC in everyday.

So I want plot a bar chart to show the uptime of each day(may boot multiple times a day).

A bar represents total 24 hours, and if my PC is working in a time range, I want the corresponding region of the bar of that day colored `red`, `white` vice versa.

Now I use class `UptimeRangeInDay` to represent a time range, and one day may have several `UptimeRangeInDay` object which have same `self.day` but different `self.start_point and end_point`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class UptimeRangeInDay:
    btime: int
    uptime: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        bdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.btime)
        self.day = datetime.datetime(bdate.year, bdate.month, bdate.day)
        self.start_point = (self.btime - self.day.timestamp()) / 86400
        self.end_point = self.start_point + self.uptime / 86400
```

It will more simple if I count the total uptime each day, then plot a stacked bar chart.

But I expected a chart can show whether the PC is runing in hour or minute degree.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I count the total uptime and downtime of each day, and mark the biggest `uptime + downtime`. Fill the other day extra serveal uptime and downtime(the time spent to 0) let `uptime + downtime` of that equal the biggest, then plot it.